# Is there a way to define all value types of deeply nested objects as all being of type string?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Assume this nested object:

```
const nestedObj = {
  definition: {
    name: 'Mike',
    prop1: {
      value1: 'This is a string',
      prop2: {
        value2: 'String again',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Is there a discreet way of doing something like:

```
type NestedObj = {
  definition: AllValuesAreOfTypeString
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](https://flow.org/try/#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) what you're looking for?

Otherwise, by writing the exact code you already have, you've given `nestedObj` the following type:

```
{
  definition: {
    name: string,
    prop1: {
      value1: string,
      prop2: {
        value2: string,
      },
    },
  },
}
```

If you, for example, extract one of the nested properties:

```
const nestedProp = nestedObj.definition.prop1.value1;
```

It will be correctly typed as `string`:

```
(nestedProp: string);
```

And if you try to set a deeply nested property as a different type:

```
nestedObj.definition.prop1.value1 = 1;
```

You will get a type error:

> Cannot assign `1` to `nestedObj.definition.prop1.value1` because number [1] is incompatible with string [2].

You also cannot set other props on the object, as it's sealed:

```
nestedObj.undefinedProp = 'test';
```

Finally, you can actually save the type of `nestedObj` by doing the following:

```
type NestObject = typeof nestedObj;
```

You could then, for example, use this type on other objects:

```
const nestedObj2: NestedObject = {
  definition: {
    name: 'test',
    prop1: {
      value1: 'value1',
      prop2: {
        value2: 'test',
      }
    },
  },
};
```

So if you were to define `nestedObj2` in a way that did not match `nestedObj1`, you would get an error:

```
const nestedObj3: NestedObject = {
  definition: {
    name: 1, // Error!
    // Cannot assign object literal to `nestedObj3` because 
    // number [1] is incompatible with string [2] in property 
    // `definition.name`.
    prop1: {
      value1: 'value1',
      prop2: {
        value2: 'test',
      }
    },
  },
};
```

([Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBGCm14BMDyAjAVjAvDA3gFAwzLwBmAlmJVJeAFwHElwCGAtvEwOQCylANbweAGhYkADgCcQkgIxMirVgDc2AGwCu8RTB4AVABaUIMUzDYxo06gHMxE1jLkAmJU5Xrt8d-oDKULZgdpZ2bNSOKiQAvuIqcSyJMQDchISgkLAISMhMNva4cIhQKBiYAHRkVDR04BUuChXeOvJphDmlaFhVFNS09GANsk0tukVtMAD0UzAAotKy0umdZT1aYNXUKAAKI0U8pdA87VAAnpLwMAByJWuY8MCweOeXIOTFueXtmdCfXeU-LcvlhHs9mCQtrVBh4VGBONx9EcoFFnCM9MpomM9DxsaiVI0-JjojAxn5DiV8awYk5ErFxKl0r9YDZ8kFCnhVt1MK5ejUBvV4VwfuA-lzygBmJjAgGgp5FTFQgVgWGsIWI+TxNFyDGeUmaVq8PFagkjIl6khk3jIqmxWla5IpIA))

Edit: added the first example as I may have misunderstood the question first time around.